# access github text files from specific merge dates

Tags: r, github, version-control, archive

I'm trying to download a text file from github from particular dates. I need to run this script daily, so that it downloads from file versions which are 1,2,3 and 4 weeks behind the current date. I'm able to browse previous versions of the file, and get their url but i need to a way to get these urls computationally, corresponding to the required dates. Anyone any ideas ?

```
library(tidyverse)
## current version 
f1=read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv")

## from three days ago.
f2=read_csv("https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/1dbdf338e2b545025b0b7d3f79bdfed9bbe9a07f/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv")
```

Comment: You're going to need to clone the repository.  Walking the history in any meaningful way with the GitHub API is wildly inefficient (because in general, doing it over HTTP with a paged API is wildly inefficient) and you'll likely exhaust your rate limit.